# How to make sure concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor stores data in the correct order?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have a dataframe that consists of all the links that I will use *requests* to scrape the data.

I am using *concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor* to loop through all the links from the dataframe and scrape it.

When the scrapings are done, I want to store all the data back into the dataframe. How can I assure that the data is stored in the correct order?

Below is what I've tried:

It seems working, but if one of the requests is slower than the other, then the order is messed up.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor: 
    res = [executor.submit(scrape_product, headers,proxy,"https://www.example.com"+str(df1.iloc[n][2])) for n in range (0,len(df1))]
    concurrent.futures.wait(res)
    for n in range (0,len(df1)):
        df1.loc[n, 'Data']=res[n].result()
```

Comment: First, if you are looping through the `res` list of `Future` instances in the order of creation, it does not matter what the order of completion is; the results will be the same regardless so I question your assertion that "the order is messed up." Second, it should not even be necessary to call `concurrent.futures.wait(res)` since `res[n].result()` will wait for the nth future to complete. Third, you have an indentation problem.

Comment: Based on what you said on the first point, I’ll check again if it’s really messed up. I am quite confusing on this concurrency. Thanks.